# I am getting error while inserting to SQL

Tags: c#, sql

```
datetime=Datetime.Now;
string strquery = @"INSERT INT0 [Destination_CMS].[dbo].[Destination_CMS_User] 
     values('" + userid + "','" + email + "','" 
     + userType + "','" + userStatus + "','" + processed + "','" 
     + datetime.ToLongDateString() + "')";
cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, con);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I am getting error:
Incorrect syntax near 'Destination_CMS'.

Comment: Also do not concatenate your data with SQL query. use parameters.

Comment: When posting code, remember to indent 4 spaces.

Comment: It is **very important** that you learn about SQL injection and the use of parameters.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your sugestions.
looking forward for using parametrised query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've written `INT0` rather than `INTO`.

Also, use [parameterized queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28Parameterized_Queries.29).

Answer (score 2):

You should try to change `INT0` to `INTO`.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INT0 [Destination_CMS].[dbo]
```

I think its INSERT INTO rather than INT0 (zero)

Answer (score 1):

Print the query to the screen, and verify where the syntax error is.

Next to that; use parametrized queries, like this:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO [tablename] ( column, column ) VALUES (@p_param1, @p_param2)";
var command = new SqlCommand (query);
command.Parameters.Add ("@p_param1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are risking sql injection, if not using parametrized queries..

Your problem looks solved, so my next question would be, why not use an ORM like NHibernate/EF etc.., depending on your requirements offocourse, but ADO.NET plumbing in my books is where performance is an absolute issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could write this as a stored procedure instead, which has the advantage of making typos like this a lot easier to spot and fix.